# What type of increment is this?

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function

Can anybody formulate this incrementation below? I tried exponential, Quadratical and some polynomial formulas but not really successfully.

```
10
20
30
40
50
61
71
81
92
102
113
123
134
145
156
167
178
189
201
213
225
237
250
263
277
291
306
322
339
356
375
395
416
439
464
492
522
555
591
631
676
727
783
846
917
997
1100
1200
1300
1400
1600
1800
2000
2200
2400
2700
3100
3500
3900
4400
5000
5700
6400
7300
8300
9500
10800
12300
```

Comment: are the data "exact" or affected by "error" / "approximation", i.e., are you looking for an interpolating function/polynomyal, or for an *approximating* function (e.g. by least square error) ?

Comment: A sixth-order polynomial can fit this with a coefficient of determination equal to 0.9999132067.

Comment: @GCab It can be close. I just need a similiar model.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks for the answer, I have tried to fit with your way, I got very close but I didn't understand how to apply coefficient of determination. Can you please help?

Comment: @savante: The coefficient of determination is just a measure of how good the fit is. In this case, you would say it like this: the sixth-order polynomial explains 99.99132067% of the variation in the dependent variable. By the way, I just used Excel to do the fit.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks a lot, Is it possible that you share your equation please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quintic+fit+395,416,439,464,492,522,555,591,631,676,727,783,846,917,997,1100,1200,1300,1400,1600,1800,2000,2200,2400,2700,3100,3500,3900,4400,5000,5700,6400,7300,8300,9500,10800,12300) says that the data fits this quintic polynomial quite well:
$$
0.000515017 x^5 - 0.0290963 x^4 + 0.766803 x^3 - 7.35982 x^2 + 54.3594 x + 332.974
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very useful site...